# Start subshells with assignment and wait for that

Tags: bash, shell

How to start some subshells with assignment of variable and wait since all finished?

```
#!/bin/bash

#some code about $FILE="$1"

cat "$FILE" | while read -r HOST || [[ -n $HOST ]];
do
    echo "$HOST";
    URL="http://$HOST";  QUEST1=$(curl -Is --connect-timeout 200 --max-time 200 "$URL" | head -1);
    P1=$!
    URL="https://$HOST"; QUEST2=$(curl -Is --connect-timeout 200 --max-time 200 "$URL" | head -1);
    P2=$!
    
    echo "$P1 $P2"
    wait $P1 $P2
    R1=$( echo "$QUEST1" | grep -o " 200" );
    R2=$( echo "$QUEST2" | grep -o " 200" );
    echo "$R1 $R2"
    
    if [[ "$R1" || "$R2" ]]; then
    echo "FOUND!";
    fi

done
```

This doesn't work. `echo "$P1 $P2"` is empty because I'm in subshell. I want that starts contemporary so I don't have to wait since the first finished.

Ok, this is a basic question, but I want to understand how to apply this to other cases. Please I don't want external file.

**EDIT**
For who did not understand. I want to put `$QUEST1` and `$QUEST2` in background to speed up the time and waiting since finished without using extra files. I read so much but nothing that solves. Thank you

Comment: Put a valid shebang and paste your script at https://shellcheck.net  , also see [How can I read line-by-line or field-by-field](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001) and also there appears no background job so the the `$P?` are empty...

Comment: @Jetchisel "Put a valid shebang and paste your script at shellcheck.net " I'm not used to do it. I've putted, but you can't see it. It's unuploadable here. Says that all it's good. I think you don't have read. I need background task for assignment because it's faster to do some action contemporary. Every request has a timeout time and in this way the time reduces significantly. If want to put the code in shellcheck.com i added #!/bin/bash upward.

Comment: shellcheck detects 3 problems still `echo "$P1 $P2" is empty because I'm in subshell.` inside the loop or after the loop? If after the loop - read https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/024 and fixing SC2002 will fix your problem. Please read [ask]. `wait $P1 $P2` you did not start anything in the background, so you can't wait. Did you meant to add `&` to run it in the background? `Please i don't want external file.` - please use external file. Using files is _the way_ of working with shell.

Comment: @KamilCuk "Using files is the way of working with shell." -> there are the variables. "```wait $P1 $P2``` you did not start anything in the background, so you can't wait" it's all right, but i want to do it in background!! Seems like that shellcheck it's the solution to all problems. Here there are people. I want to put this 2 subshell in background together and wait since they finished. Still linking things. It's not the answer. Thanks tha same

Comment: Just to be sure, do you see that assigning the subshell output to variable implies that the parent shell will wait for the end of **all the subshell subprocess**, even if the inside command of the subshell is a background job ?

Comment: As an example : `x=$( { { /bin/sleep 10 ; echo out1; echo out2; } | head -1; } & ); echo $!` will _block_ the parent shell for ten seconds. And `$!` is correctly defined **in the subshell**, but it is the subshell `$!`, not the parent one. To get the expected `$!`, you have to transmit it through stdout, stderr or files, or named pipe, or etc.

Comment: @Zilog80 "As an example : x=$( { { /bin/sleep 10 ; echo out1; echo out2; } | head -1; } & ); echo $! will block the parent shell for ten seconds. And $! is correctly defined in the subshell, but it is the subshell $!, not the parent one." Then try but I think u're the ONE! The last part it's not lovely "To get the expected $!, you have to transmit it through stdout, stderr or files, or named pipe, or etc", but you are a master! Tnks

Comment: For the above' example, you got the parent `$!`, if you want to get the background job pid for `$!` **subshell**,  you can use the stdout way : `x=$( { { { /bin/sleep 10 ; echo out1; echo out2; } | head -1; } & } ; echo $! );`.  But you **can't expect having it in a deterministic order**.

Comment: @Zilog80 "For the above' example, you got the parent $!, if you want to get the background job pid for $! subshell, you can use the stdout way : x=$( { { { /bin/sleep 10 ; echo out1; echo out2; } | head -1; } & } ; echo $! );. But you can't expect having it in a deterministic order." Wait Zilog80, I don't have my shell in this computer. Then I try. Answer the question. Your answer it's good. So i can up this.

Comment: MMMM ```x=$( { { /bin/sleep 10 ; echo out1; echo out2; } | head -1; } & ); echo $!```Tryed. ```$!``` Gives no pid. It was a beautiful way.

Comment: As explained above, you don't get the `$!` subshell pid but the parent one. Then nothing. If you want the subshell one, try something like `subpid=$( { { { /bin/sleep 10 ; echo out1; echo out2; } | head -1; } 1>&2 & } ; echo $!)`

Comment: @Zilog80 then I try this ```subpid=$( { { { /bin/sleep 10 ; echo out1; echo out2; } | head -1; } 1>&2 & } ; echo $!)```. Parents and pids are make mee crazy. Answer the question complete I'll take u up. U are the only one that gives me the solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a resume of the comments :

Assigning the subshell output to a variable / using the subshell output (STDOUT) implies that the parent shell will wait for the end of all the subshell subprocess, even if there is an inside *backgrounded* command.

As an example :

```sh
x=$( { { /bin/sleep 10 ; echo out1; echo out2; } | head -1; } & ); \
echo "Wrong child PID : $!"
```

This will block the parent shell for ten seconds. But here you got the parent shell `$!` , not the one defined in the subshell. To get the expected `$!`, you have to transmit it in some ways to your parent shell (through STDOUT, STDERR or files, or named pipe, or etc.). You can achieve that through STDOUT for example like that :

```sh
subpid=$( { { { /bin/sleep 10 ; echo out1; echo out2; } | head -1; } 1>&2 & } ; \
echo $!)
```

Here, as your subshell sends its command output to STDERR and only outputs the child PID `$!` on STDOUT, the command will execute nearly immediately (no blocking I/O for the parent shell then).

As you expect to avoid I/O as almost as possible, and if you only need the subshell `$!` to wait for the subprocess, you can just rely on the fact that the parent shell will wait **all STDOUT output** from the subshell. Then your actual commands are sufficient, no need to know the subshell `$!` :

```sh
URL="http://$HOST";  QUEST1=$(curl -Is --connect-timeout 200 --max-time 200 "$URL" \
| head -1);
```

However, if you need to know the child PID of your subshell (note that this PID will be *here* a **shell pid**, not the one of the **curl** or the **head** command) and **wait** for the subshell command to finish, then you could do something like that to have a **near deterministic order**  (will not work if your subcommand does not include at least one pipe) of the output :

```sh
x=$( { spid=$( { { { /bin/sleep 10;echo out1;echo out2; }|head -1;} 1>&2 & };echo $!);} \
2>&1 ; echo "SUBPID=$spid" )
```

This will give in `x`, after **ten seconds**  : `SUBPID=<subshell child pid> out1`.

At this time, this *SUBPID* will no longer exist (or will not be "your" subshell child pid anymore), but you can log it or do anything you may want  with it.

Your command will be then something like :

```sh
URL="http://$HOST";  QUEST1=$( \
{ subpid=$( { { curl -Is --connect-timeout 200 --max-time 200 "$URL" | head -1; \
 } 1>&2 & } ;echo $!); } 2>&1 ; echo "SUBPID=$subpid" );
```

And the first entry in `QUEST1` should be *SUBPID=<subshell child pid>* followed by the curl first line output.

To clearly show that the shell will wait, you can test it with a ten seconds sleep inside with google.com :

```sh
URL="http://www.google.com";  QUEST1=$( { subpid=$( \
{ { { curl -Is --connect-timeout 200 --max-time 200 "$URL"; sleep 10; } | head -1; \
 } 1>&2 & };echo $!); } 2>&1 ; echo "SUBPID=$subpid" );
```

### Update

After our exchanges, i get that you are looking for an asynchronous *waitable*  subprocess in a subshell from which you need to get the output when it is finished, all that **without using temp files nor named pipes**.

There is a solution requiring no temp files, no disk write I/O and based on [@hhtamas solution to create an anonymous fifo](https://superuser.com/questions/184307/bash-create-anonymous-fifo) for an anonymous pipe instead of a named pipe.

Here, at first, an simple example of this solution, **followed with an implementation for your use case** (many curl call through subshell).

### Example solution :

```sh
#!/bin/bash
# We use the bright solution from @htamas to create an anonymous pipe
# in the fds of our current shell.
# see: https://superuser.com/questions/184307/bash-create-anonymous-fifo
#
#
# 1. Creating the anonymous pipe
#

# start a background pipeline with two processes running forever
tail -f /dev/null | tail -f /dev/null &
# save the process ids
PID2=$!
PID1=$(jobs -p %+)
# hijack the pipe's file descriptors using procfs
exec 3>/proc/"${PID1}"/fd/1 4</proc/"${PID2}"/fd/0
# kill the background processes we no longer need
# (using disown suppresses the 'Terminated' message)
disown $PID2
kill "${PID1}" "${PID2}"
# anything we write to fd 3 can be read back from fd 4

#
# 2. Launching an "asynchonous subshell" and get its output
#

# We set a flag to trap the async subshell termination through SIGHUP
ready=0;
trap "ready=1" SIGHUP;

# We launch our subshell for the subprocess "sleep 10" with its output
# connected to the standalone anonymous pipe.
# As the sleep command as no output, we add "starting" and "finish".
# Note that as we send the output elsewhere than STDOUT, it's non blocking
# Note also that we send SIGHUP to our parent shell ($$) when the command finishs.
x=$( { echo "starting"; sleep 10; echo "finish"; echo "EOF"; kill -SIGHUP $$; } >&3 & )

# We now wait that our subshell terminates, it will terminate within the sleep command.
# Will waiting, we can do stuff. Here we just display "Waiting.." every seconds.
while [ "${ready}" = "0" ]; do
   echo "waiting for subshell..";
   sleep 1;
done;

# We close fd 3 early as we should no more output from the subshell
exec 3>&-

# We recover our subshell output from the out point of the autonomous pipe in y
line=""
y=$( while [ "${line}" != "EOF" ] ; do 
      read -r -u 4 line; 
      [ "${line}" != "EOF" ] && echo "${line}"; 
     done );

# And display the output of the subshell
echo "Subshell terminate, its output : ";
echo "${y}"

# close the file descriptors when we are finished (optional)
exec 4<&-
```

This solution requires the `/proc` filesystem, which is common on many actual UNIX. Explanations are provided as comments in the script.

*minor edit:* Better subshell identity process, more process info at wait time, handling potential crash of the subshells.

### Implementation for your use case :

```sh
#!/bin/bash
#
# Create the anonymous pipe.
# 
# Parameters: None.
# Returns:
#   0 : Success.
#   1 : Failed to launch tails.
#   2 : Failed to exec.
#   3 : Failed to kill tails process.
function CreateAnonymousPipe() {
  # We use the bright solution from @htamas to create an anonymous pipe
  # in the fds of our current shell.
  # see: https://superuser.com/questions/184307/bash-create-anonymous-fifo
  #
  local pid1
  local pid2
  # start a background pipeline with two processes running forever
  tail -f /dev/null | tail -f /dev/null &
  [ $? != 0 ] && return 1;
  # save the process ids
  pid2=$!
  pid1=$(jobs -p %+)
  # hijack the pipe's file descriptors using procfs
  exec 3>/proc/"${pid1}"/fd/1 4</proc/"${pid2}"/fd/0
  [ $? != 0 ] && return 2;
  # kill the background processes we no longer need
  # (using disown suppresses the 'Terminated' message)
  disown "${pid2}"
  kill "${pid1}" "${pid2}"
  [ $? != 0 ] && return 3;

  # anything we write to fd 3 can be read back from fd 4
  return 0;
}
#
# Launch asynchronuously a curl process in a subshell.
# 
# Parameters: { URL } { indice }
#   URL : URL for the curl call.
#   indice : numeric identifier for this call
# Returns:
#   0 : Success.
#   1 : Missing parameters
#   2 : Failed to launch curl subprocess.
#   3 : Failed to access /proc
# STDOUT: PID of the corresponding subshell if success.
function CallCurl() {
  if [ $# != 2 ] ; then
    echo "CallCurl: URL and indice parameter are mandatory." 1>&2
    echo "          CallCurl { URL } { indice }." 1>&2
    return 1;
  fi
  [ ! -d /proc ] && return 3;
  local url="$1"
  local indice="$2"
  local subshell_PID
  # We launch our subshell for the subrprocess curl with its output
  # connected to the standalone anonymous pipe.
  # The curl process output is prefixed with its indice in the URL arrays.
  # Note that the subshell first renames itself with a specific identifier, 
  # curl_<indice>, and that we escape $BASHPID to use its pid for that :
  #   1) We can't use $$ to get the subshell PID as it is not a shell variable that
  #      can be evaluated at execution. As it is "immutable" from the shell point of
  #      view, it'll be always evaluated at first expansion, thus the parent shell PID.
  #   2) We don't rename after subshell launch using $! as its PID, at this time the
  #      subshell could have already terminated and its possible that another process
  #      have since been launched with this PID.
  # Note that we send its output elsewhere than STDOUT (to >&3), so it's non blocking.
  # Note also that we send USR1 signal to our parent shell ($$) when the command finishs.
  subshell_PID=$( { { local my_pid; 
                      eval my_pid="\${BASHPID}";
                      printf 'curl_%s' "${indice}">/proc/"${my_pid}"/comm 2>/dev/null;
                      curl -Is --connect-timeout 200 --max-time 200 "${url}" | head -1 |
                      { read -r line; echo "${indice}: ${line}"; };
                      kill -USR1 $$; 
                    } >&3 & 
                  } ; 
                  echo $!; )
  [ $? != 0 ] && return 2;
  echo "${subshell_PID}"
  return 0;
}
#
# Main URL processor, launch curl subprocess asynchronuously.
# 
# Parameters: { URL ... }
#   URL : URL to call with curl.
# Returns:
#   0 : Success.
#   1 : URL parameter(s) missing
#   2 : Failed to launch curl subprocess.
#   2 : Failed to create anonymous pipe.
# STDOUT: Processing and the outputs of the curl commands
function CurlProcessor() {
  if [ $# = 0 ] ; then
    echo "CurlProcessor: URL parameter is mandatory."  1>&2
    echo "               CurlProcessor { URL ... }." 1>&2
    return 1;
  fi
  local indice=0
  local isalive=0
  local -a URLarray
  # Feed the URL array
  while [ $# -gt 0 ] ; do URLarray+=("$1"); shift; done
  # Initialize a set of flags for each URL
  local -a ready
  for ((indice=0; indice < ${#URLarray[@]}; indice++)) ; do ready+=(0); done
  # Initialize an array of subshell PID for each URL to monitor
  local -a pid
  for ((indice=0; indice < ${#URLarray[@]}; indice++)) ; do pid+=(0); done
  # Initialize an array of subshell output for each URL 
  declare -a output
  for ((indice=0; indice < ${#URLarray[@]}; indice++)) ; do output+=(""); done
  # We create the anonymous pipe
  CreateAnonymousPipe
  [ $? != 0 ] && return 3;
  # Set a trap to catch USR1 and check which subshell are still alive through /proc
  # Local handler for the signals
  function trap_handler() {
    for indice in "${!pid[@]}" ; do
      if [ "${pid[${indice}]}" != "0" ] ; then 
        isalive="$(cat /proc/"${pid[${indice}]}"/comm 2>/dev/null)" 2>/dev/null; 
        [ "${isalive}" != "curl_${indice}" ] && ready[${indice}]=1;
      fi
    done
  }
  trap trap_handler USR1 2>/dev/null;
  # Now launch all the subshell
  for ((indice=0; indice < ${#URLarray[@]}; indice++)) ; do
    pid[${indice}]=$(CallCurl "${URLarray[${indice}]}" "${indice}"); 
    [ $? != 0 ] && return 2;
  done
  # We now wait that our subshells terminate.
  # Will waiting, we can do stuff. Here we just display "Waiting.." every seconds.
  local all_finished=0
  local num_finished=0
  local last_num_finished=0
  local direct_check_timer=0
  while [ "${all_finished}" = "0" ]; do
     # We check each URL subshell flag and loop till there is at least one unfinished.
     all_finished=1
     num_finished=0
     for ((indice=0; indice < ${#ready[@]}; indice++)) ; do 
       if [ ${ready[${indice}]} = 0 ] ; then
         all_finished=0; 
       else
         ((num_finished++));
       fi
     done
     echo "waiting for subshells.. ${num_finished}/${#ready[@]} finished.";
     sleep 1;
     # In case one or more subshell have crashed and thus wont send the USR1 signal, 
     # we launch here the handler to check the states of the subshells after 5sec
     # if there is no subshell termination in the interval.
     if [ "${all_finished}" = "0" ] ; then
       if [ "${last_num_finished}" = "${num_finished}" ] ; then
         ((direct_check_timer++))
         if [ "${direct_check_timer}" = "5" ] ; then
             echo "More than 5 seconds with no progress, doing a direct check."
             direct_check_timer=0 
             trap_handler
         fi
       else
         direct_check_timer=0 
       fi
     fi
     last_num_finished="${num_finished}"
  done;
  # All subshell have finished, we send EOF in the autonaumous pipe
  echo "EOF" >&3
  # We close fd 3 early 
  exec 3>&-
  # We recover our subshells outputs from the out point of the autonomous pipe
  local line=""
  local control=""
  while [ "${line}" != "EOF" ] ; do 
    read -r -u 4 line; 
    if [ "${line}" != "EOF" ] ; then
      # Each line should have "indice: " as a prefix to identify the URL associated
      indice="${line/: */}"
      if [ "${indice}" ] ; then
        control="${indice/[0-9]*/}"
        if [ "${control}" = "" ] ; then
          if [ "${output[${indice}]}" != "" ] ; then
            output[${indice}]="${output[${indice}]}\n${line/[0-9]*: /}"
          else
            output[${indice}]="${line/[0-9]*: /}"
          fi
        fi
      fi
    fi
  done
  # close the file descriptors when we are finished (optional)
  exec 4<&-
  # And display the output of the subshells
  echo "Subshells have all terminated, the output : ";
  for ((indice=0; indice < ${#URLarray[@]}; indice++)) ; do 
    echo "Output from URL ${URLarray[${indice}]} :"
    echo "${output[${indice}]}"
  done
  return 0;
}
#
# An example call of CurlProcessor
#
CurlProcessor "http://www.google.com" "http://stackoverflow.com/" "http://en.cppreference.com/"
```

With the example call, you'll get the following output :

```
waiting for subshells.. 0/3 finished.
waiting for subshells.. 3/3 finished.
Subshells have all terminated, the output :
Output from URL http://www.google.com :
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Output from URL http://stackoverflow.com/ :
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Output from URL http://en.cppreference.com/ :
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
```

And when [fastly is down](https://downdetector.com/status/fastly/news/392592-problems-at-fastly/), you'll get :

```
waiting for subshells.. 0/3 finished.
waiting for subshells.. 2/3 finished.
waiting for subshells.. 2/3 finished.
waiting for subshells.. 2/3 finished.
waiting for subshells.. 2/3 finished.
waiting for subshells.. 2/3 finished.
waiting for subshells.. 2/3 finished.
More than 5 seconds with no progress, doing a direct check.
waiting for subshells.. 2/3 finished.
waiting for subshells.. 2/3 finished.
waiting for subshells.. 2/3 finished.
waiting for subshells.. 2/3 finished.
waiting for subshells.. 2/3 finished.
More than 5 seconds with no progress, doing a direct check.
waiting for subshells.. 2/3 finished.
waiting for subshells.. 2/3 finished.
waiting for subshells.. 2/3 finished.
waiting for subshells.. 2/3 finished.
waiting for subshells.. 2/3 finished.
More than 5 seconds with no progress, doing a direct check.
waiting for subshells.. 3/3 finished.
Subshells have all terminated, the output :
Output from URL http://www.google.com :
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Output from URL http://stackoverflow.com/ :
HTTP/1.1 503 Backend unavailable, connection timeout
Output from URL http://en.cppreference.com/ :
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
```

(Perfect time to test the script ^^.)

Comment: To clearly show that the shell will wait, you can test it with a ten seconds sleep inside with google.com :
@Zilog80 Tried the last (to clarify) the example with google.com ```URL="http://www.google.com"; QUEST1=$( { subpid=$( { { { curl -Is --connect-timeout 200 --max-time 200 $URL; sleep 1; } | head -1; } 1>&2 & };echo $!); } 2>&1 ; echo "SUBPID=$subpid" );``` there's the subpid. WORKS. UP

Comment: What is your output of  `echo $QUEST1` after the command ?

Comment: Works woks. Excuseme. My output 4 the echo $QUEST1 it's perfect. thanks @Zilog80

Comment: You can store and wait for it Example : `{ { sleep 10; } 1>&2 & } ;echo "waiting for $!";  wait $!`. If you **"cut"** the STDOUT with `1>&2 &`, the bash shell will not wait for the subshell to terminate. But you can then use the correct `$!` and wait for it later...

Comment: "You can store and wait for it Example : { { sleep 10; } 1>&2 & } ;echo "waiting for $!";  wait $!. If you "cut" the STDOUT with 1>&2 &, the bash shell will not wait for the subshell to terminate. But you can then use the correct $! and wait for it later.." Read it

Comment: I've added a solution for your goal, with an implementation for multiple async curl calls.

Comment: @SantooDeathXXXXXXXXXXXXXX Minor revision to provide more infos while waiting. Perfect time to test it with the _fastly effect_.

Comment: "I've added a solution for your goal" "Minor revision" @this time wanna say u stop yoursel! Good code. By too long. I'm not a lover of anonymous pipes, nested functions, trap(music), indice, isalive. In my script case (finished) I added in the while only one file pid. It waits since all curl calls HTTP and HTTPS finish. It's fast like yours but simpler. Beautiful implementation of   ```/proc/"${PID1}"/fd```for who want to use it. But it's not for me. I don't have any info for you I don't test this file. BUT THANKS THA SAME ^^. You'r a fool. This answer is absurd. GO out to play :)

Answer (score 0):

## Solved from myself using @Zilog80 tecnique

## ====================================

## EDIT:

## THIS POST IT'S ALL WRONG.

## EXTERNAL FILE IT'S NEEDED.

## ====================================

P.S. Just see his answer to understand (the important part about STDOUT 1>&2 so you don't create wrong child)

I understand that in subshell `( )` you can assign variables that are read out from the external script.

**Grouping blocks of code in curly brackets there's not a subshell**. Commands in curly are anonymous function `{ }`. (Ref [https://tldp.org](https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/special-chars.html#CODEBLOCKREF))

---

So at this time you can write

`( export QUEST2=$(curl -Is --connect-timeout 2 --max-time 2 $URL | head -1) ) 2>&1 & P2=$!`

and I have the PID of the subshell and the quest complete.

All the code will be:

```
#!/bin/bash

FILE="$1"

cat "$FILE" | while read -r HOST || [[ -n $HOST ]];
do
    echo "$HOST";
    URL="http://$HOST";  ( export QUEST1=$(curl -Is --connect-timeout 2 --max-time 2 $URL | head -1) ) 2>&1 & P1=$!
    URL="https://$HOST"; ( export QUEST2=$(curl -Is --connect-timeout 2 --max-time 2 $URL | head -1) ) 2>&1 & P2=$!

    
    echo "$P1 $P2"
    wait $P1 $P2
    R1=$( echo "$QUEST1" | grep -o " 200" );
    R2=$( echo "$QUEST2" | grep -o " 200" );
    echo "$R1 $R2"
    
    if [[ "$R1" || "$R2" ]]; then
    echo "FOUND!";
    fi

done
```

where `$FILE` is **textfile.txt** with a list of host/ip like

```
google.com
software.net
hacking.org
nasa.gov
```

now u can start your script to try if a site has http or https protocol active

(USELESS LIKE NO OTHER :() --> it was to understand how to fork good

TNKS TO **@Zilog80**.

Comment: Just see your answer, so it seems you get it. See my comment on STDOUT anyway, that's the important part.

Comment: @Zilog80 "Just see your answer, so it seems you get it. See my comment on STDOUT anyway, that's the important part." Now works good. But can't take variables from subshell.... MMMMMM . Doesen't work. Done

Comment: ...Also if i use export.

Comment: From a subshell, there's no easy way to get any variables/values except for its exit code. As say in comments, you can send the value(s) through STDOUT to the parent shell or through a fifo, a named pipe, etc. But not directly. From the parent shell perspective the subshell is by essence an isolated shell that should not alter parent shell context nor variables.

Comment: It's not impossible. To resume, you need to launch curl in a subshell, wait for it, get its output and the subshell pid. So something like that : `URL="http://www.google.com";  MYVAR=$( { { subpid=$( { { { curl -Is --connect-timeout 200 --max-time 200 $URL;  } | head -1; } 1>&2 & };echo $!; ) ; }  ; echo "${subpid}";  } 3>&1 2>&3 | { read SUB; echo SUBPID="\"${SUB}\";";  read OUT1; echo "OUT1=\"${OUT1/$'\r'/}\"";}  ) ; eval $MYVAR`. After that, you'll get the curl output in `${OUT1}` and the subshell pid in `${SUBPID}`.

Comment: If you need also to have an "asynchronous" subshell and wait for it at a moment in your parent shell, it's possible through signals and a pipe to get the output. An example : `[ ! -p ./mypipe ] && mknod ./mypipe p; ready=0; trap "ready=1"
SIGHUP;  x=$( { sleep 10; kill -SIGHUP $$; echo "finish" > ./mypipe; } 1>&2 & )
; while [ "${ready}" = "0" ]; do echo "waiting for subshell.."; sleep 1; done; y
=$(cat ./mypipe); echo " Subshell terminate, its output : $y";`

Comment: @Zilog80 "If you need also to have an "asynchronous" subshell and wait for it at a moment in your parent shell, it's possible through signals and a pipe to get the output. An example : [ ! -p ./mypipe ] && mknod ./mypipe p; ready=0; trap "ready=1" SIGHUP;  x=$( { sleep 10; kill -SIGHUP $$; echo "finish" > ./mypipe; } 1>&2 & ) ; while [ "${ready}" = "0" ]; do echo "waiting for subshell.."; sleep 1; done; y =$(cat ./mypipe); echo " Subshell terminate, its output : $y";" trap for me it's only music and i don't have a pipe. Question closed. (thanks).